# WebForms and MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, webforms

I'm working in a Banking Online Platform written in WebForms and I'm wondering if the same could or should be written in MVC.
I've read a lot on MVC but i didn't tried yet but i must ask a question for the experts.

Every transaction has a 3 Stage Process where the users input the data, review the data and gets a 3rd step where get's the confirmation. I currently have 40+ processes like this. The way i do it? Single ASPX with MultiView.

How can i do the same in MVC? Would i have 40+ x 3 Views (120+ aspx) ?

Thank U all.

Comment: What is your objective here? Are you trying to improve the code by rewriting it, improve the user experience, improve application performance? Or is this just a programming exercise for you, with no need for there to be any benefit to the bank?

Comment: Technology improovement. The code is VB and need to be re-written in C#, .NET framework upgrade also. Need to decide. One big gain is the lack of ViewState so performance would be upgraded to.

Comment: Im looking at doing something similar, and am faced with the same decision; just wondering what you ended up choosing?

Answer (score 0):

The same can be achieved in MVC by using partial views.

MVC has full control over the rendered HTML and JavaScript frameworks is much easier to implement. It is also a lot more easier to write unit tests.

It is also 'lighter' in the sense that it does not have any View State events (which is the thing that makes Web Forms big when working with big data)